# Connect to elasticsearch 2.4.4 with spark 2.x

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch

From offical DOC we can see that :

> elasticsearch-hadoop allows Elasticsearch to be used in Spark in two
>   ways: through the dedicated support available since 2.1 or through the
>   Map/Reduce bridge since 2.0

But when I try the **through the dedicated support** way like below:

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark;

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
        .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        .set("es.nodes", "localhost")
        .set("es.port", "9200")
        .set("es.resource", "test/main")
        .set("es.index.auto.create", "true");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile("file:///home/zht/PycharmProjects/test/text_file.txt");
JavaRDD<Map<String, String>> formattedRdd = input.map(...);

JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(formattedRdd, "test/spark");
```

And run commind line:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.es.resource=test/main --jars $SPARK_HOME/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.4.4.jar --class org.spark_examples.something.launchSpark SparkExamples-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I got an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.TaskContext.addOnCompleteCallback(Lscala/Function0;)V
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addOnCompleteCallback method was removed from the TaskContext in Spark 2.0. Spark 2.0 is not binary compatible with previous releases.

If you are using maven to build this project use the below code snippet.

```
 <dependency> 
          <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId> 
          <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId> 
          <version>5.1.2</version> 
     </dependency>
```

If not, please use elasticsearch-hadoop jar version greater than version 5.

Reference:
[Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/905)